# How to obtain the hex value 0xffff corresponding to the decimal value -0.000061 in the table below?

Tags: opentype

Right at the beginning of this page [The OpenType Font File](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/otff.htm) you'll find this table, with examples of the F2DOT14 format for a 16-bit signed fixed number with the low 14 bits of a fraction.

[image]

I couldn't obtain the hex value 0xffff for the decimal -0.000061. By the way the mantissa -1 seems to be wrong and the value for the fraction should be 1/16384, instead of 16383/16384, unless I'm missing something related to the two's complement notation used to express a negative value in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mantissa and fraction values listed are entirely correct: the F2DOT14 field encodes numbers as the arithmetic computation `mantissa + fraction`, not as "signed mantissa with unsigned concatenated fraction remainder".

As such, if you want `-0.000061`, you have to start with the signed integer `-1` in the first two bits (11) and then *add* the positive value 16383/16384 in the last 14 bits (11111111111111), such that `mantissa + fraction` = `-1 + 16383/16384` = `-1/16384`, which in turn is encoded using the 16 bit code `0xFFFF`

Comment: Finally, I agree with you.